# Replace line number in text file using java

Tags: java, input, javafx, output

I need replace specific line number in my text file. I wrote code and it's working but some times my code replacing 2 line. What is bad? There is faster way to replace not using my method? 
Ok this is code

```
int last=0;
Boolean brak=false;
try{

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("last.txt"));
String strLine;
int count=0;
//Read File Line By Line
while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
  // Print the content on the console
  if(count==1) {last=Integer.parseInt(strLine);


  }
  count++;
}
//Close the input stream
br.close();
}catch (FileNotFoundException e){//Catch exception if any
        System.out.println(e.toString());
      brak=true;
    }
catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();}
try(Connection c = MsSqlConnect.getConnection())
{
    System.out.println(last);

    String SQL = "Select ob_id,ob_dokMagId,dok_NrPelny,ob_TowId,tw_Nazwa,ob_IloscMag,ob_WartBrutto,dok_Typ from dok_Pozycja dp "
+ "RIGHT JOIN dok__Dokument ON dok_Id=ob_DokMagId "
+ "LEFT JOIN tw__Towar ON tw_Id=ob_TowId "
+ "Where ob_TowRodzaj=1 AND dp.ob_id>"+last;
ResultSet rs = c.createStatement().executeQuery(SQL);
int tlast=last;
while(rs.next()){
    data.add(new OrderSU(rs.getInt("ob_dokMagId"), rs.getString("dok_NrPelny"), rs.getInt("ob_TowId"), rs.getString("tw_Nazwa"), rs.getInt("ob_IloscMag"), rs.getFloat("ob_WartBrutto"),rs.getInt("dok_Typ")));
last=rs.getInt("ob_id");
  }
if(brak==true){
    try(PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("last.txt", true)))) {
out.print("0"+"\r\n"+last);
}catch (IOException e) {
    //exception handling left as an exercise for the reader
    }
}
else 
{
     try {
         System.out.println(last+" "+tlast);
BufferedReader file = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("last.txt"));
String line;String input = "";
    int count=0;
  while ((line = file.readLine()) != null){
        input += line + "\r\n";
             if(count==1) {
                input = input.replace(Integer.toString(tlast), Integer.toString(last));
            } 
            count++;
        }

        file.close();
        System.out.print(input);
 FileOutputStream File = new FileOutputStream("last.txt");
    File.write(input.getBytes());
    file.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Problem reading file.");
    }
}
c.close();
```

I using this function 2 times. First line save last ID from DB and second line saving last ID from another DB. I need take this ID to last changed db rows.

Comment: instead of unconditionally adding all lines and using `input.replace()`, why not conditionally add lines except for when count==1?  I'm pretty sure your error is that you are replacing all instances of the number `tlast` with the number `last`

Comment: I add more information in post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`input` is cumulative.  That is, if you've read 5 lines from the file, `input` will contain all 5 lines.  So if you said

```
input = input.replace(Integer.toString(tlast), Integer.toString(last));
```

at that point, since `input` contains the text of 5 lines, it would perform the replacement on all 5 of those lines.

If you want to do the replacement on just one input line, you'll need to fix your logic.

Comment: True i dont think about what. I think i must take line nr x change what need and add to input. I added more information to post. This is possible FileNotFoundException catch when another function don't close file?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to hold the last line read in a different variable. "Input" holds all thelines read so far.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
line = line.replace(Integer.toString(tlast), Integer.toString(last));
```

Put it before `input += line + "\r\n";`